# Ansible doesn't execute commands on remote server

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using **Ansible 2.1.1.0** intalled by pip on OS X "El capitan".
And I have tried with a very simple configuration:

```
#/etc/ansible/hosts
[webservers]
my.remote.server
```

Using the variable **ansible_user** to connect through ssh using the corresponding public key:

```
#/etc/ansible/group_vars/webservers
---
ansible_user: my_user
```

All seems to be fine when I try to ping the server `ansible webservers -m ping`:

```
my.remote.server | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Nonetheless when I try to run any command on the remote server it gets executed on my local machine, for example running `ansible webservers -m shell -a "echo $HOSTNAME"` should display **my.remote.server**, but displays this instead:

```
my.remote.server | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
my.local.server
```

Any idea what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `"echo $HOSTNAME"` is being evaluated in your local shell before being passed to the remote server over SSH. Try this:

```
ansible webservers -a hostname
```

Or this:

```
ansible webservers -m shell -a 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

Comment: That works fine @mwp, so the problem was caused by my ignorance! haha, thanks man

Comment: What would you say about this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274380/enable-apache-site-using-ansible